# Delete an entry from an nested list if two entries at the same index are identical

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list which looks like this:

```
l = [['h', 'i', 'l'],
     ['m', 'b', 'x'],
     ['u', 'o', 'l'],
     ['f', 'j', 'x']]
```

As you can see the entry at index 2 is identical for sublist 1 and 3 and for sublist 0 and 2.

How can I remove sublists that have identical entries at a specific index?

Expected result:

```
nl = [['h', 'i', 'l'],
      ['m', 'b', 'x']]
```

I tried to use the `set()` function, but that did not work out.

Can somebody help?

Comment: what happens if the input is like this 
l = [['h', 'i', 'l'],
     ['m', 'i', 'x'],
     ['u', 'o', 'l'],
     ['f', 'j', 'x']
    ]
'i' is repeated in second list

Comment: Hi @pavanskipo, I basically just want to compare the entries at index 2.

Comment: ah okay, was thinking of algorithm taking lists vertically, like ['h', 'm', 'u', 'f'], ['i', 'b', 'o', 'j'], ['l', 'x', 'l', 'x'] and then remove duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one-line solution :

```
[l[i] for i in sorted({e[2]: i for i, e in zip(range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1), l[::-1])}.values())]
```

**output:**

```
[['h', 'i', 'l'], 
 ['m', 'b', 'x']]
```

here is a one for loop solution:

```
uniq_value = set()
final_list = []
for e in l:
    if e[2] not in uniq_value:
        uniq_value.add(e[2])
        final_list.append(e)

final_list
```

**output:**

```
[['h', 'i', 'l'], 
 ['m', 'b', 'x']]
```

I've been benchmarking @FilipMłynarski, @Exa and my one for solution:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters
import numpy as np

b = BenchmarkBuilder()

def _filip(x):
    stack = [set() for _ in x[0]]
    for row in x:
        if all(i not in seen for i, seen in zip(row, stack)):
            for idx, i in enumerate(row):
                stack[idx].add(i)
            yield row

@b.add_function()            
def filip(l):
    return list(_filip(l))

@b.add_function()
def exa(l):
    t = []
    for sl in l:
        for st in t:
            for (v, o) in zip(sl, st):
                if v == o:
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            t.append(sl)
    return t

@b.add_function()
def kederrac(l):
    uniq_value = set()
    final_list = []
    for e in l:
        if e[2] not in uniq_value:
            uniq_value.add(e[2])
            final_list.append(e)

    return final_list

@b.add_function()
def exa_fix_index(l):
    t = []
    for sl in l:
        for st in t:
            if sl[2] == st[2]:
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            t.append(sl)
    return t

@b.add_function()
def mathfux(array, idx=2):
    array = np.array(array)
    ith_column = array[:, idx]
    u, good_indices = np.unique(ith_column, return_index=True)
    new_array = array[good_indices]
    new_array = new_array.tolist() #if you need to convert back to list
    return new_array

@b.add_arguments('Size of list of lists')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 7):
        size = 10**exp
        list_of_lists = [[choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(size)]
        yield size,  list_of_lists

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I added an example for specific indexes in my answer, feel free to benchmark that against your function instead for the sake of consistency.

Comment: @Exa I just added your fix index solution

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `set()` won't work since you want to remove entries that have at least one repeating element, **not entire list**. We could create function that keeps track of seen elements that we want to avoid in future (here list of sets `stack`) while iterating over supplied list, to `yield` elements that have **all** of it's values unique.

```
l = [
    ['h', 'i', 'l'],
    ['m', 'b', 'x'],
    ['u', 'o', 'l'],
    ['f', 'j', 'x'],
]

def fix(x):
    stack = [set() for _ in x[0]]
    for row in x:
        if all(i not in seen for i, seen in zip(row, stack)):
            for idx, i in enumerate(row):
                stack[idx].add(i)
            yield row

print(list(fix(l)))  # -> [['h', 'i', 'l'], ['m', 'b', 'x']]
```

Comment: Hi @Filip, thanks your for your answer. So your solution also removes elements that are identical at index 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Although Filip's answer looks cool, it's a bit too complicated and - as discovered - pretty slow. Simply keeping track of all unique lists and scanning them at each iteration to determine whether our current list is valid (has uniformly unique elements), does the trick.

```
def fix(l):
    t = []
    for sl in l:
        for st in t:
            for (v, o) in zip(sl, st):
                if v == o:
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            t.append(sl)
    return t
```

This performs at `~2.2946` while Filip's hits `~6.1039` according to `timeit.timeit` (copy-pasted solutions in terminal):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: fix(l)) # mine
2.3752248109999528
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: list(fix(l))) # Filip
6.073348348000309
```

For specific indexes, a few adjustments give us:

```
def fix(l, i):
    t = []
    for sl in l:
        for st in t:
            if sl[i] == st[i]:
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            t.append(sl)
    return t
```

Benchmarking 3rd index:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: fix(l, 2))
0.9275596050001695
```

As expected, far quicker when you know what you want to get rid of.

To avoid unnecessary memory overhead if you're dealing with large sums of data, add `yield sl` right over `t.append(sl)` and drop the `return` statement (in all examples).

Comment: Hi @Exa, thanks your for your answer. So your solution also removes elements that are identical at index 0 and 1?

Comment: @Exa If you claim your answer is faster than Filip's it's suggested to provide details on how you came to the conclusion that your answer is faster than his like `timeit` analysis or whatever you did to come to this conclusion.

Comment: Heya @gython, yeap, this will remove all subsequent lists that have elements equal to any index of the last seen lists, at any index (let me know if you wanted something more specific). And apologies for not including time proof, did it now.

Comment: @Exa I've been benchmarking your solution against Filip's one and mine, you can check my answer

Comment: @kederrac it's odd that there are inconsistent results between timeit and benchmark. Also your function is different than mine and Filip's since it only checks for one index.

Answer (score 1):

It seems for me that `numpy` is the easiest way to do it in your case:

```
def delete_by_index(array, idx):
    array = np.array(array)
    ith_column = array[:, idx]
    u, good_indices = np.unique(ith_column, return_index=True)
    new_array = array[good_indices]
    new_array = new_array.tolist() #if you need to convert back to list
    return new_array

print(delete_by_index(l, 2)) #prints expected result
```

Two important things I did there:

- extracted `ith_column` which is `['l', 'x', 'l', 'x']` for `i=2`;
- used `np.unique` method which returns (sorted) unique items `['l', 'x']` and their indices `[0, 1]` accordings to [these docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

What about efficiency, `numpy` usage should be faster than using `for` loops, because all it's actions performs loops that are written in C.